# Square root by approximation

Tags: javascript, node.js, algebra

I am trying to solve this challenge but I don't know if my code is wrong, or if the phrasing of the challenge is wrong. The algorithm says:

1. Choose two numbers `S,E`. The `X` square root must be in `[S,E]` interval.
2. Choose the precision desired `e`.
3. The middle value of the current interval, `M`, will be a good approximation.
4. While the interval `[S,E]` is greater than `e`, do:

   - find the middle value of the current interval `M`;
   - `if M^2 > x`, `E = M`, otherwise, `S = M`;
   - When the length of 
     our interval is smaller than `e`, square root of `X = M`.

My code below produces an infinite loop:

```js
e = 0.001; //I want square root of 10
n = "10";
x = parseInt(n);
E = (x / 2);
S = 1;
M = ((E - S) / 2);
tam = (E - S);
while (tam >= e) {
 console.log(M)
 if ((M * M) > x) {
   E = M;
 } else {
   S = M
 };
 M = ((E - S) / 2);
 tam = (E - S);
}
console.log(n + ": " + M);
```

Thanks

Comment: The midpoint of an interval `[S,E]` is `(E+S)/2`, not `(E-S)/2`

Comment: @PM77-1 implied by the while loop running for as long as tam >= e? It'll break out when tam < e.

Answer (score 1):

You're not finding the midpoint of the interval correctly. You should be adding `E` and `S` and dividing by two instead of subtracting.

```js
e=0.001; //I want square root of 10
   n="10";
   x=parseInt(n);
   E=(x/2);
   S=1;
   M=((E+S)/2);
   tam = (E-S);
   while(tam>=e){
       console.log(M)
       if ((M*M)>x){E=M;}else{S=M};
       M=((E+S)/2);
       tam = (E-S);
   }   console.log(n+": "+M);
```